# Find and replace instances of grouped hashtags

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, markdown

I have a markdown string like so:

```
var str = "# This is a title ## This is a subtitle ###Paragraph title";
```

I want to add a hashtag to every title so when the markdown renders as HTML, they all render as the title tag below. I want to achieve the following string:

```
var str = "## This is a title ### This is a subtitle ####Paragraph title";
```

I've tried doing this with a simple replace:

```
str.replace("###", "####");
```

But now when I go to do the next tag above, it will match instances of the tag below because it also has 2 hashtags in:

```
str.replace("##", "###");
```

This is no good and I guess this needs to be done with regex. Is it possible to match and replace these in the way I want and how would it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very simple using grouping.

Use `replace(/(#+)/g, "$1#")`

[Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pU9vQ1/1) with regex explanation in left side.

Explanation:

"search all one and more # and replace each matched group  with one extra #"

```js
var str = "# This is a title ## This is a subtitle ###Paragraph title".replace(/(#+)/g, "$1#");

document.write(str);
```

Comment: Thanks! This will be the accepted answer. I wonder if you could go the extra mile and tell me how I would avoid matching hashtags in a body of text in the string (for example twitter hashtags). The title hashtags will always be at the start of a line with a carriage return before.

Comment: Please can you ask another question with some example with exact requirement. Keep it simple here.

Comment: No need to use the grouping - see my answer

Comment: @AndyNewman What is the difference between grouping and non-grouping match. Is there any benefit on performance?

Comment: Thanks, I'll put it in another question now.

Answer (score 0):

To replace every instance of a string of n hashes with n + 1 hashes, you can use `str.replace(/#+/g, '$&#')`